# Google Map API cannot be inserted into url including in Google Map Json

Tags: android, google-maps, retrofit, google-maps-android-api-2, google-geocoding-api

I have a this url shown below.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=MY-KEY-API&latlng=40.9927242,29.0231916
```

I want to get json result from url by Retrofit part shown below.

```
public static final String URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com";

@GET("/maps/api/geocode/json")
    Call<Location> getInformation(@Query("latlng") String lat);

Call<Location> req = Manager.getInstance().getCity("40.9927242,29.0231916");
```

The response is shown below.

```
response : Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.9927242%2C29.0231916}
```

API key cannot be inserted into the url part even through it defines in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

google_maps_key.xml

```
<string name="google_maps_key"
        templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">
        MY-KEY-API
</string>
```

When I click url, the error is defined in json format because of not adding API into the url.

```
{
"error_message": "You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account",
"results": [],
"status": "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly add an API key to your Geocoding API request (i.e. `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=AIza...`).

The key you inserted into your Android Manifest is used by the Maps SDK for Android to load a map on your Android app.

The Geocoding API on the other hand does not use nor recognize that Android key. It needs its own key. Right now your call to this API is keyless which is why you are getting that REQUEST_DENIED error.

**Side-note:** It's recommended that you use another API key for web services because the key in your xml file should be [Android restricted](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key#restrict_key).

As for how to restrict your Geocoding key, take a look  at the techniques mentioned in Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#best_practice_list), "On mobile apps that use Maps Web Service APIs" section.

Hope this helps you.